# What effect does having npm in devDependencies have?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm looking at a project that has the following as part of the package.json `"devDependencies": {`
`"npm": "3.8.3",`

Given that the nodejs install already includes npm what effect does this have when I do `npm install`?

Comment: It's an internal project one of our teams had been working on. I believe it may have referenced `npm` in scripts in the past but no longer does so shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The globally installed `npm` package and the package mentioned in `devDependencies` as in your case are far away in case of usage from each other.

The package mentioned in `devDependencies` is treated same as like all the other packages in dependencies by requiring the package function/object. Ex. `const obj = require('npm');` the npm package will be in use if you are using any `npm-command` from your project which contains an `npm` keyword. Ex. from any customize script which runs `npm install <pkg-name>` command.

Unless and until in and out of your project the each `npm` command refers to the global installation of `npm package` and `npm -v` always show the globally installed `npm-package` version.

Hope this will help you!